# Strange I/O error. Poco::WebSocket. ARM

Tags: linux, websocket, arm, poco

I have strange problem with Poco::WebSocket on ARM.
Under Linux / Windows all works fine.

So, thereis server written on Poco and running on Ubuntu 13.04 x64.

I trying to connect to this server from ARM device (Linux, uClib) using same version of Poco, compiled for my device:

```
try{
    Poco::Net::HTTPClientSession hSession;

    hSession.setHost( "192.168.1.1" );
    hSession.setPort( 8890 );

    Poco::Net::HTTPRequest hRqst;
    hRqst.setURI( "/wcs" );

    Poco::Net::HTTPResponse hResp;

    printf( "OPEN\n" );
    Poco::Net::WebSocket hSocket( hSession, hRqst, hResp );

    printf( "SOCKET OK\n" );
}catch( Poco::Exception & e ){
    printf( "FAIL: %s\n", e.displayText().c_str() );
}
```

Output:

> OPEN
>
> FAIL: I/O error: 0: 192.168.1.1:8890

Any ideas how to resolve this problem?

Comment: I found that static linking works. But i need dynamic linking ):

Comment: Problem was solved by using newer version of uClibc, because problem with pthread library (infinity loop).